# Python multiprocessing processes and pipes - is 700 processes reasonable?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

The server is running Red Hat in 32bit with 8 cores.

The company classes that must be instantiated are not pickleable.

I tried threading but reaching 4 to 7 concurrent threads dropped performance to that of sequential processing. This was due in part to my ignorance, PySimpleClient and the underlying C++ implementation.

I tried multiprocessing with Queues but this was not robust and did not improve performance.

I currently am running 60 multiprocess processes each with a pipe successfully. The performance is great and robustness so far is excellent.

But I need 700 processes minimum. Is 700 reasonable?

Comment: Why would you need as many as 700 processes? There are other approaches to concurrency - microthreads, greenlet, Stackless...

Comment: Why not try it and see? It seems you already have an implementation with 60 processes...

Answer (score 0):

I would say it wouldn't be reasonable on a 32bit machine.  I would want to run that kind of load on a 64bit machine with ample memory to handle any overhead that that number of processes might need.

Comment: This, and you won't (shouldn't) experience performance increases over more than 8 processes anyway, if they are fully utilizing the processor.

Comment: I agree with @Wug here. Personally, I would try to use one process per core, and then use threading inside each process to maximize core utilization.

Comment: Chances are also that the overhead of 700 python processes would bring the machine to a grinding crawl anyway, on all but fairly serious hardware.

Comment: I would not have expected going over the core count would improve performance, but the company SW runs thousands of C/C++ threads concurrently I don't know if that is relevant but I seem to get better service if I make all of my requests at once.

Comment: Threads in processes. Interesting. Do the threads share the memory space of the parent process?

Comment: It could be how the multiprocessing and multithreading are done that are causing the slow downs, but what you are describing sounds counter intuitive to what I've seen in practice.  Typically more threads, past the core count, usually can cause a degradation in the speed, unless of course you are holding threads in a thread pool.

Comment: Multiple python processes with multiple threads, the threads in each process would share the python process's memory while each python process would be a separate container for the threads in a sense. This would be an ideal setup as long as you do not need to do any interprocess synchronization, but that would not be overly difficult to overcome.

Comment: @sean, I suppose the other thousands of threads might suffer when my 60 are handled. If this is the case I will need to change my approach.

Comment: It depends on the job, but it seems that your requirement of hundreds of threads running may be slight limitation in the software.  If you can minimize the work done in each thread and you can do 8 (or however many cpu cores you have) of them at a time passing them new work as needed then that may be a better approach, but hard to judge out of context to your software.

Comment: @sean, One of the hardware components I need to turn on takes a minute. There are 66 antennas each with 10 of these components and only three of these components in each antenna can be turned on at a time. The underlying software is synchronous for this power up. Adding the other components starts pushing just the expected power up sequence to over two hours when done sequentially. I have at most 30 minutes to power up and collect the data. I was very happy to have a pipe-process solution that at least worked robustly and quickly. I never achieved a robust thread solution but bug in C was fxd.

Comment: Actually your solution is ok for your problem. The threads will not really bottle neck the system in this sense, the context really helps.  Basically you should be ok with running more threads to perform these start up and reading procedures, as they do not all nesscarily happen at once. Just could starve your available memory on your system though because of the shear number of threads being spun up at once.  Just watch your memory consumption and if it starts to get overly high I would rethink your solution. Also take a look at a thread pool library as I think that might make things easier.

Comment: @Nisan.H, re threads in processes. Does each process get an interpreter? If not it appears the GIL will run all the threads sequentially. http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/01/python-threads-and-the-global-interpreter-lock/

Comment: @Buoy, yes, each process gets its own interpreter. The threading isn't necessarily useful for increasing the efficiency inside a single process, but can help in some cases--those where you are waiting on other components in particular. All you get out of multithreading in python is context switching--and for you application this is actually useful. You can spawn X threads per process, each bound to an antenna, then cycle through them and put each back to sleep when it's done, until the next cycle. sean's suggestion for thread pooling covered that.

Comment: Sean, @Nisan.H, Thanks a lot for your caveats and details. I have a better understanding the pros and limitations.